# Where's the 'Skyline Trail Loop'? How does it differ from 'Skyline Trail'?

Tags: hiking, nova-scotia

The pages beneath for [Skyline Trail](https://www.alltrails.com/trail/canada/nova-scotia/skyline-trail?ref=result-card) and [Skyline Trail Loop](https://www.alltrails.com/trail/canada/nova-scotia/skyline-trail-loop?ref=result-card) exhibit their differences.

[image]

1. I found only [the former (Skyline Trail) on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Skyline+Trail/@46.7464466,-60.8912931,14z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x4b671943b56930f1:0xc57fe73e41a3eb72!8m2!3d46.741985!4d-60.8809999). Where's the Loop?
2. How does it differ from 'Skyline Trail'?

Comment: Given that the website you've linked contains actual maps of the trailing, I don't see how this is a valid question.  AllTrains frequently has minor variations on the same trial listed as separate trails (or something even complete duplicates). Voting to close...

Comment: @Doc I don't see how to access the maps without creating an account.

Comment: Oh wait, if you have an ad blocker on, the (non-PDF) maps are hidden. I missed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The links you provided show the difference clearly! In fact I am not sure why are you asking this question while the answer is in the links you provided (as @doc said in the comments). I am gonna assume that for some reason the maps weren't loaded when you visited the page so you weren't able to see them.

Here's the difference between the trail and the trail loop:

[image]

Comment: +1. Thanks. You're correct that 'for some reason the maps weren't loaded when you visited the page so you weren't able to see them'. I did turn off my ad blockers...

Comment: in the photo there's a little typo: train = trail..